# SwiftUI: animating between Single and HStack views

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, hstack

Goal:

1- Shows a view (Blue) that covers entire screen 
[image]
2- When tapped on bottom (top right corner), it shows an HStack animating right side HStack (Green)  "Slide Offset animation".
[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showgreen = false


    var body: some View {


    NavigationView {

        HStack {
            Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)

            if showgreen  {
            Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .offset(x: showgreen ? 0 : UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            .animation(.easeInOut)
            }

           }

    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
      Button(action: { self.showgreen.toggle() }) {
              Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
              })
       }

    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())


    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        .colorScheme(.dark)
        .previewDevice("iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)")
    }
}
```

The code works, however I cannot get the Green "Slide Offset animation" to work. Really appreciate any help! : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `if` conditional, you need the green rectangle to be already present, and just offscreen. When `showgreen` toggles, you need to shrink the size of the blue rectangle, which will make room for the green rectangle.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showgreen = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .frame(width: showgreen ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 : UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)

                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: { self.showgreen.toggle() }) {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
            })
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```